# trigger.io iOS Facebook apprequests incorrect parameter quotation

Tags: ios, facebook, trigger.io, facebook-app-requests

I'm making an apprequests using native Facebook plugin as follows:

```
forge.facebook.ui(
    {
        method: "apprequests",
        title: "How well do you know your friends?",
        message: "Play this friends guessing game with me. This is just like the game Guess Who with Facebook.",
        to: 100005076427220
    },
    function(response) {
        alert('succ:' + JSON.stringify(response));
    }, function(response){
        alert('error:' + JSON.stringify(response));
    }
);
```

On Android everything looks fine. Here is the debug output:

```
[   INFO] D/Forge   (11035): Native call facebook.ui with task.params: {"method":"apprequests","title":"How well do you know your friends?","message":"Play this friends guessing game with me. This is just like the game Guess Who with Facebook.","to":100005076427220}
[   INFO] D/Forge   (11035): Returned: {"content":{"to[0]":"100005076427220","request":"1404036919832397"},"callid":"39281D3C-EACE-4070-937C-3BE1852DA12F","status":"success"}
```

Unfortunately on iOS is not. Here is the debug output:

```
[DEBUG] Native call: {
[DEBUG]     callid = "BF08EEC1-175D-483F-846B-319721A82B04";
[DEBUG]     method = "facebook.ui";
[DEBUG]     params =     {
[DEBUG]         message = "Play this friends guessing game with me. This is just like the game Guess Who with Facebook.";
[DEBUG]         method = apprequests;
[DEBUG]         title = "How well do you know your friends?";
[DEBUG]         to = 100005076427220;
[DEBUG]     };
[DEBUG] }
[DEBUG] 2013-10-30 15:53:53.283 Forge[732:907] -[__NSCFNumber UTF8String]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1cdd9c20
[DEBUG] Returning to javascript: {
[DEBUG]     callid = "BF08EEC1-175D-483F-846B-319721A82B04";
[DEBUG]     content =     {
[DEBUG]         message = "-[__NSCFNumber UTF8String]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1cdd9c20";
[DEBUG]         type = "UNEXPECTED_FAILURE";
[DEBUG]     };
[DEBUG]     status = error;
```

As you can see, the parameter method = apprequests; is not quoted as it is in Android
method = "apprequests"; It is not from my code but from the public plugin itself.

Is it possible that this makes the error?

I'm using Platform version v2.0.3 and Facebook module v2.0.1

Comment: Does this still happen if you pass the "to" parameter as a string, i.e. {to: "100005076427220"}?